# Modelling game foliage, such as trees, bushes and grass

Tags: modeling, uv, game-engine, optimization

So I'm currently practicing my skills as a environmental artist.

The scene I am currently making will involve a lot of foliage, specifically a Hatian forest.

I have been trying various ways to make trees including: Mtree addon, skin modifier with a subdivision surface, hair particle system for leaves and branches etc... the trees are then exported to UE4.

I'd love if everyone could share their processes for creating foliage for games, how would you model them, how would you optimize them. How do you create the LOD's for them (blender to unreal), how do you unwrap and texture them?

My Mtree haddon trees come out with 2million triangles, my skin modifier trees look to ridgid, and my particle system branches all go in the wrong directions (palm tree) haha

Any advice would be great, cheers

Comment: Generally, I make the tree through whatever method, with a lot of (too many) faces/verts, etc... and then use a _Decimate Modifier_ to bring the count down. You'd be surprised how low you can go without loosing a noticeable amount of detail.

Comment: See I've used the decimate tool and yes I definitely agree you can go quite low, as low as 25% in some cases without losing the objects shape but it can create some nasty geometry sometimes, how would you go about UV unwrapping it after?